# how to make validation maximum 3 selections of checkboxes but i still want to uncheck the the checked ones and change to the other options

Tags: reactjs

So I have a Checkbox component that is a child of CheckboxChip (multiple checkboxes as chips) component that I use on a page:
the sexualOrientation is an array

i only have 2 states on the page:

```
let [selected, setSelected] = useState([]); for storing selected option (string) inside array

const setSexualOrientation = (val) => {

    if (selected.indexOf(val) === -1 ){
      setSelected([...selected, val])
    } else {
      setSelected(selected.filter(item => item !== val));
    }
  }
```

and in the page render like this

```
<FormGroup>
      <FormControl>
        <Typography variant="h6" mt={2} sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>My sexual orientation is</Typography>
        <Typography variant="body2" mt={2} sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Select up to 3</Typography>
        <Grid container columns={{ xs: 6, sm: 8, md: 12 }}>
          <Grid >
            <CheckboxChip values={sexualOrientation} label="" onChange={setSexualOrientation}></CheckboxChip>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <FormControlLabel
          value="Show my orientation on my profile."
          control={<Checkbox />}
          label="Show my orientation on my profile."
          onChange={onDisplaySexualOrientation}
        />
        <CustomizedButton label="Continue" onClick={()=>navigate('/gender-preference')}></CustomizedButton>
      </FormControl>
    </FormGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```js
const setSexualOrientation = (val) => {
    if (selected.indexOf(val) === -1 ){
     if(selected.length < 3)  // append the value if the length is < 3
      setSelected([...selected, val])
    } else {
      setSelected(selected.filter(item => item !== val));
    }
  }
```